# Node.js require is not loading local file

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var typeOfUser = require('../js/type.js');  
var typeOfUser = require('./js/type.js');  
var typeOfUser = require('./type.js');
```

None of the above lines (written within a file named `dashboardJS.js` situated in folder named `js`) are working. `require` here is not working. The folder structure is:

```
Project_on_dairy/MDMS/js/type.js  
Project_on_dairy/MDMS/js/dashboardJS.js
```

Comment: The last should work, as well as `require("type.js")`

Comment: If it is written within a file named 'dashboardJS.js', then you should require it instead. Like this, require('./dashboardJS.js')

Comment: no it is not. Even if i specify the absolute path for file type.js,it will not load that file.

Comment: What is the error message you get for `require('./type.js');`?

Comment: What is the result of console.log(typeOfUser) after your require ? undefined ?

Comment: Define "not working". What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? Were there any error messages?

Comment: I suggest you use path module for building the path

Comment: thank you everyone. It worked.The problem was in type.js

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will works if you try with something like this ?

```
var typeOfUser=require(__dirname + '/MDMS/js/type.js');
```

Hope it helps.